# Is it correct to pass json as string?

Tags: c#, json

I have doubt is it correct/acceptable technique to pass json as string parameter to the API? Is there any implication while passing json as string variable to the API method? Please advice

Comment: How would you pass json around otherwise, if not as string?

Comment: HI normally json will be like this 
{"blkHouseNo":"11","streetName":"Beach ROAD","postalCode":"123456","storeyNo":"22","unitNo":"2",} but I want to pass as {"PayLoad":"{\"blkHouseNo\":\"183\",\"streetName\":\"Beach ROAD\",\"postalCode\":\"123456\",\"storeyNo\":\"22\",\"unitNo\":\"2\"}"}  is it right way ?

Comment: If you are planning to extract information out of the JSON then why do not you post it in the API and let it be mapped with the Classes and properties. It would be convenient for you.

Comment: I am using IBM API Connect to publish the API's . This product has limitation that Input request fields mapping individual level  between REST Service parameters to SOUP service parameters . if I need to add new parameter then every time I need to update REST SERVICE and SOUP service parameter mapping . this is causing to republish the product each and maintenance cost increases .So I plan to pass all JSON fields under one field called :"Payload" as shown below . To make this change I looking for experts help is industry standard to pass json values under field as string ? Please advice

Answer (score 2):

Yes but please check string is correct or not.
You can check your json using this url: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can pass json as a string, almost always, but there will be nothing in place to ensure that the string is, in fact, valid json.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any problem with this.
Json is just a string formatted well to more readable by human and machines. so it should send as string :)

Comment: hanks for your quick reply . Currently Any payment API's are following this approach. I just need to confirm is it industry standard process or not. Please help to advice

Comment: This standard way and there isn't any problem with this approach. if you have sensitive content in your JSON string  is another discussion and you should encrypt the sensitive fields and data and use secure underlying channels for requests like HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// 1 QUESTION
  // class home_class
  // {
  //        function test()
  //        {
  //                echo "Hello World Message";
  //        }
  // }
  // $res = new home_class;
  // echo $res->test();

// 1 QUESTION
// $country = array("India","USA","UK");

// foreach($country as $row) {
//    echo "Contry Name:".$row . "<br>";
// }


// $jsoncountry = array();
// foreach($country as $row) {
//     $jsoncountry[]["Contry Name"] = $row;
// }

// print_r(json_encode($jsoncountry));


// Since there is no one-size-fits-all solution to the challenges that images pose, you must carefully consider how you want to manage them based on the unique needs of your content.
?>
```